# Regular Expression Replace One Character with Space

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a timestamp in a AWS log file with this format: 2021-04-04T12:21:29Z

This Regular Expression will capture the timestamp into three groups:

```
(?<utcDate>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(?:T)(?<utcTime>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})
```

Outputting: `2021-04-04T12:21:29`

I'm trying to replace the T with a space to create a valid timestamp format to import into a SQL timestamp column via AWS Athena. I'm already using date_parse concatenating the two utcDate and utcTime groups into a timestamp in my select statement. But I want to have a timestamp in my table so I can query on the timestamp in my where clause.

When I make the above regular expression into one group comprised of subgroups, the T still gets returned even though it's defined in a Non-Capture Group. Is it possible to match the one character T and replace it with a space?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What tool are you using for matching and replacing?

Comment: I'm using regular expression input in my AWS Athena create external table statement.

Comment: Non-capturing does not mean "not matching". Capturing is just saving a part of a match in a separate memory buffer. You need to access groups, or replace.

Comment: OK, but replacing can only be done AFTER the initial regular expression runs?

Comment: Can you use 2 capture groups in the replacement like `$1 $2` ? There are 2 capture groups instead of 3 as this part `(?:T)` can be written as just `T`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is replace the `T` with a space: `replace(column_name, 'T', ' ')`. If you want a `TIMESTAMP` from your ISO 8601 string: `from_iso8601_timestamp(column_name)`.

Comment: Yes, but that replace function can only be run after the regular expression is done. Can the replace be done in the regular expression?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by that?